# How do you map props in react-native when their is a require property

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Now when these tags are in component file how does one map through various values.

Example

```
1. <Image source = require("")/>
2. const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require("../../assets/sounds/slack.mp3")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map like this:

```
const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require("../../assets/sounds/slack.mp3")

return sound.map((item, index) => (
<YourComponent key={index}>{item.value}</YourComponent>
))
```

Comment: i tried that but to it is not working for me, source undefined error always props up

Comment: Check your array with console.log() if your array is not undefined you can map like this. If it is undefined you can push your items in array with yourArray.push(yourItems);

Comment: in the flatlist i am passing the value as following <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => playSound(item.sound)}> and when I console.log the value in the function I am getting the value only when i put the value in const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      require({soundValue})
    ); the error gets thrown